# Android google map with current position

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I'm writing an application that among other things should draw a map with the current device position and a remote point.
I started from the example created by Android Studio (Google->Google Map Activity).
I just add the code to get the current location:

```
package it.tux.mapper.activities;

import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

import java.util.Objects;

import it.tux.mapper.R;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback, LocationListener {
    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_LOCATION = 11;
    private static final int LOCATION_UPDATE_DELAY = 1000;

    private final String gps_provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;

    private GoogleMap map;
    private Location location;
    private LocationManager location_manager;
    private View layout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        if (mapFragment != null)
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        //USER CODE

        layout = findViewById(R.id.map);
        assert layout != null;

        location = new Location(getString(R.string.location_provider));
        location.isFromMockProvider();

        initLocalization();
        //
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == PERMISSION_REQUEST_LOCATION) {
            if (grantResults.length == 1 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Snackbar.make(layout, R.string.fine_location_access_granted, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startLocalization();
            } else {
                Snackbar.make(layout, R.string.denied_fine_location_access_rationale, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        map = googleMap;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        this.location.set(location);

        if (map != null) {
            LatLng base = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(base).title(getString(R.string.destination_base_label)));
            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(base));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {
        return;
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
        return;
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
        return;
    }

    private void requestLocationPermission() {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
            Snackbar.make(layout, R.string.denied_fine_location_access_rationale,
                    Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction(R.string.ok, new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MapsActivity.this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                            PERMISSION_REQUEST_LOCATION);
                }
            }).show();

        } else {
            Snackbar.make(layout, R.string.denied_fine_location_access_warning, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_LOCATION);
        }
    }

    private void initLocalization() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Snackbar.make(layout,
                    R.string.fine_location_access_granted,
                    Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startLocalization();
        } else {
            requestLocationPermission();
        }
    }
    
    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private void startLocalization() {
        try {
            location_manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            if (!location_manager.isProviderEnabled(gps_provider)) {
                Intent gpsOptionsIntent = new Intent(
                        android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(gpsOptionsIntent);
            } else {
                location_manager.requestLocationUpdates(gps_provider, LOCATION_UPDATE_DELAY, 2, this);
            }
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

The code seems to work, i.e. no exceptions are triggered and `onMapReady`, `onLocationChanged` and `onRequestPermissionsResult` events are correctly fired.
The map is just empty. And the use count of the Api key is 0.

The manifest has the correct permission entries:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

And also the GoogleApi key is correctly set (I have a developer account):

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

Where's my error?

Comment: Open the Google Map app in your device and check whether map is visible on that or not.

Comment: this's the first check I did. Google Map app was working while my app wasn't. As I stated below the problems comes into the very first connection attempt you make against (I suppose) the Google API authenticator. If this connection abort because of some weird firewall rules the authentication fails and the app will not work (without exceptions). After a first succesful attempt, going trough DMZ, it keeps working even if you fall back on the MZ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be related to the internet connection used to make the first connection to google api service. Under certain firewall the connection is probably blocked preventing a successful authorization. Changing the connection fixed this issue but I probably need to investigate deeply the API auth mechanism.